# Pandas groupby: apply vs agggregate with missing categories

Tags: python, pandas

I'm running into an issue where panda's `GroupBy.apply` and `GroupBy.aggregate` give different-shaped results when categorical data has missing values. `aggregate` retains all "known" categories, but `apply` only keeps the categories that are present in the data.

Here's a simplified example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# `missing` has 'b' category but no data uses it.
missing = pd.Categorical(list('aaa'), categories=['a', 'b'])
dense = pd.Categorical(list('abc'))
values = np.arange(len(dense))
df = pd.DataFrame({'missing': missing, 'dense': dense, 'values': values})

grouped = df.groupby(['missing', 'dense'])
print grouped.mean()
print grouped.agg(np.mean)
print grouped.apply(lambda chunk: np.mean(chunk))
```

which prints

```
            values
missing dense
a       a           0
        b           1
        c           2
b       a         NaN
        b         NaN
        c         NaN
            values
missing dense
a       a           0
        b           1
        c           2
b       a         NaN
        b         NaN
        c         NaN
            values
missing dense
a       a           0
        b           1
        c           2
```

Note that the last data frame is missing the `NaN` rows where `missing = b`. I understand why `apply` might do this (it chooses not to pass a group full of `NaN`s to the reduction function). The above snippet is just a toy example: I actually need to use `apply` to get the result I want.

**Question**: What's the best way to use `apply` but create an output shape matching the one returned by `aggregate`?

Answer (score 3):

This is in need of an enhancement pull-request to do this, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10138).

In general, you should use the simply use `.mean()` as the idiomatic way to do this (and its much faster).

Comment: Right, but I'm not actually interested in calculating the mean. Your suggestion (in the linked github issue) to use `grouped._reindex_output` internally seems to give the desired output. (I guess it's a bit unsafe to use outside of the `GroupBy` object, but I'll leave a note ;). Thanks!